# Infinite scroll upward direction

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I use infinite scroll to load more data in reverse direction?
I want to load data on scroll up instead of scroll bottom. I'm developing chatting app so i need chat style upward infinite scrolling.
thanks,

Comment: could you at leat provide some code ?

Comment: i don't know where to start.

Comment: Are you using Ionic 1.x or Ionic 2?

Comment: in ionic 1 with firebase 3